# PHP redirect to another URL after submitting a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a webform with basic info (Name, Last_Name, Date of Birth, Telephone, Email)

After submitting the form, and inserting the data of those fields into a MySQL database, I want to be able to be redirected to a different URL. I tried using the header function for php but for some reason it will not redirect me to the URL I specified.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
            $host="23.229.187.201"; // Host name 
            $username="inturuser"; // Mysql username 
            $password="admin123"; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="intur"; // Database name 
            $tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "inturuser", "hola123")or die("Error"); 
            mysql_select_db("intur")or die("cannot select DB");
// Get values from form the form 

            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $bday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['bday']));
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $ip = ""; 
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, correo, fecha_nacimiento, telefono, ip_restaurante, timestamp) 
VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$lastname.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$bday.'", "'.$phone.'", "'.$ip.'", "'.$datetime.'")';

mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful and redirect to a URL ". 
if($result)  

{
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');;
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
     }

//close connection 

   } 

   else {
echo "NO POST"; 
   }
     ?>
```

Comment: Is there any white space before the first <?php tag on page? or a blank line? or any html?. There cant be any output to browser before `header` is called

Comment: Check if you have any text before headers. Debug the page in browser and see what the headers are.

Comment: `displays message "Successful and redirect to a URL`: Did you remove that display part before posting your code here? You cant be displaying anything before you want to redirect using `header`

Answer (score 3):

You have not assigned the `$result` variable so the `if($result)` will always be false.

You should turn on your `error_reporting` to show E_NOTICE, and then you need to replace your `mysql_query` line with `$result = mysql_query($sql)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, correo, fecha_nacimiento, telefono, ip_restaurante, timestamp) 
    VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$lastname.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$bday.'", "'.$phone.'", "'.$ip.'", "'.$datetime.'")';

    mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful and redirect to a URL ". 
    if($result)  

    {
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/');;
    }
```

please remove extra semicolon from header. and assign `$result=mysql_query($sql)`

corrected solution:

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, correo, fecha_nacimiento, telefono, ip_restaurante, timestamp) 
    VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$lastname.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$bday.'", "'.$phone.'", "'.$ip.'", "'.$datetime.'")';

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful and redirect to a URL ". 
    if($result)  

    {
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    }
```